# String.replaceFirst error? Java

Tags: java, string

When I do

```
String s = "2r2";
System.out.println(s.replaceFirst("2r2","4"));
```

It works, printing 4, but when I do

```
String s = "2^2";
System.out.println(s.replaceFirst("2^2","4"));
```

It doesn't work (It prints 2^2), why? What do I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`replaceFirst` is using regular expressions syntax, where `^` has special meaning (it represents start of string or line, depending on used modifiers).

You need to escape `^` like `"2\\^2"`, or to make your life simpler use `Pattern.quote("2^2")` to do this for you.

So your code should be more like:

```
String s = "2^2";
System.out.println(s.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote("2^2"),"4"));
```

Answer (score 2):

In a regular expression, the `^` character has a special meaning.  It matches the beginning of a line.

Use `s.replaceFirst("2\\^2","4")` instead - the backslashes mean to treat `^` as a normal character, instead of giving it its special meaning.